# Class Not Found error in launching Java Applet

Tags: java, jar, applet

I have a web application which launches a Java Applet which references a large number of Jars. When I launch the applet, Java console is launched I can see these jars getting downloaded. In one of the Jars I get exception and Applet load is stopped.

Machine: Windows 7 - 64 Bit

Java Plug-in 10.80.2.15

Using JRE version 1.7.0_80-b15 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM - Using this JRE as Applet is certified on this JRE version, I even tried with latest JRE.

Exception trace:

```
    basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for 
    http://localhost:9500/***.jar?token=1497907732260dxwJEJ2dVgcJ7epg1wP11qEgom0
   basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost:9500/****/xercesImpl.jar?token=1497907732270bV1GSJKvAHvnsyCetLkp1JE8PDW
   basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for        http://localhost:9500/****/xml-apis.jar?token=1497907732277kAb6Fc3EBqsLhelOISTV73FyIvX
 basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost:9500/****/xalan.jar?token=1497907732283fAmmBmYycSZC3KvAI89phQ4yHq0
 basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost:9500/****/serializer.jar?token=1497907732289dYYFRhl8qxfEXFwbaUnW3yObqwB

 cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://localhost:9500/****/****.jar?token=1497907732362bhwRmCAl37YmOQZZJOgtnxNK8GY
 cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@f544430e: 1
 security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
 security: Grant socket perm for http://localhost:9500/****/****.jar?token=1497907732362bhwRmCAl37YmOQZZJOgtnxNK8GY :      
 java.security.Permissions@15e8b6d (
     ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost" "connect,accept,resolve")
)

 security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
 basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/****/UResourceBundle
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Component.checkCoalescing(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.***.UResourceBundle
          at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
          at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
          at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
          at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
    security: Reset deny session certificate store
    basic: Removed progress listener: 
    sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@5bdbdc
    security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

I have looked in Java Cache and opened downloaded jar and I can see the class is there.

Earlier the exception was on some other class and  then I removed all versions of Java and just reinstalled JDK 7 Update 80 32 bit and class which errors out changed.

Comment: I would suggest you look at this bit `security: Reset deny session certificate store
    basic: Removed progress listener: 
    sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@5bdbdc
    security: Reset deny session certificate store`

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).